# Book where God decides to send a second flood with interesting complications

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book at my local library in the 90s, but haven't been able to locate it again. My library has book sales where old books are sold off, and the layout has changed.

I believe it was published by Gollancz, as it had the yellow cover with black title.

In the book, God has decided to send a second flood. I think the people were selected by (reel and tape) computer. One of the people selected is a woman who has fallen in love with a priest and prays to have him defrocked. The person chosen to build the arks is a coffin-maker by trade and Noah is jealous/envious of his *unique* design. I'm not sure if the Flood is shown. A lot of the book takes place in Heaven.

There wasn't really much plot and it had a light humor feeling.

Comment: What are the interesting complications mentioned in the title? How do the people chosen interact? What do they do? Do we see the flood happen? Etc. Anything else will help tracking this down.

Comment: I think it was around that the survivors were selected by computer, that didn't take into account other traits.

Comment: "Mr. Noah and the Second Flood" by Sheila Burnford has multiple editions, including one by Gollancz. I can't determine if it's a match, the most detailed review I can see is https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/a/sheila-burnford-4/mr-noah-and-the-second-flood/ which mentions "Surviving humans meanwhile […] are blasting off from Mount Everest -- the masses heading for Mars and a computer-selected elite for the Moon".

Comment: @b_jonas [No black on yellow cover](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?911624), though.